# Find the Jacobson radical of a matrix ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, tensor-products, noncommutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Find the Jacobson radical of matrix ring $R=\mathbf{M}_2(K\otimes_kK)$ where $k =\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ and 
$K = \mathbb{F}_2[x^{1/2}]$

I tried to find the radical of this matrix ring. I have also found the solutions of the radical of those upper triangular matrix ring. But I don't think this question is the same kind of that. Please help me! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: That is, you are looking for the Jacobson radical of $K\otimes_kK$.

Comment: @user26857 Is that 0?

Comment: The fact that it is a matrix ring is not really a complicating factor: $J(M_2(R))=M_2(J(R))$, so you can forget about matrices and start looking for $J(R)$.  So you are really asking about the Jacobson radical of a tensor product. Unfortunately I have little experience thinking about those. It probably has a simple algebraic geometry explanation.

Comment: It seems that $K\otimes_kK\simeq\mathbb F_2[Y,Z]((Y+Z)^2)$, and the Jacobson radical is the ideal $(y+z)$.

Comment: @user26857 Do you mean F2[Y,Z]/((Y+Z)^2) instead of F2[Y,Z]((Y+Z)^2)? And how to see this isomorphism...

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. For the isomorphism I noticed that $K = F_2[X, Y]/(Y^2-X)$.